# How to sync remote repository and update new folder in github

Tags: git, github

I am a newbie to the GitHub world, trying to learn about GitHub.

Let's say that you already have a project on the remote repository on GitHub, and I am using a different computer that I did git push -u origin master.

So here is what I was thinking to sync from a different computer.

1. You may clone it, and try to fetch it from a remote repository and sync all the files.

All is a there better solution than this?

Comment: You are on the right path. Go ahead and clone the repository. Everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, configure your GitHub username and e-mail on your computer, using the below commands:

```
git config --global user.name "You Github username"
git config --global user.email "You GitHub email"
```

and then go and copy the link to clone your repository, after which switch to desired folder and clone it:

```
git clone copied-link
```

Now you can commit and push changes to your remote repository.